# Failed install from Xcode 6: "There was an internal API error"

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I tried running an app that works fine on my phone (ios 8.4.1) on an ipad (ios 7.1.2). Xcode says "There was an internal API error" and that's it.

I'm not sure how to interpret the logs. What's wrong? How do I fix this?

The ipad log:

```
Aug 29 17:39:23 Esters-iPad lockdownd[52] <Notice>: 00201000 set_response_error: handle_get_value GetProhibited
Aug 29 17:39:23 Esters-iPad lockdownd[52] <Notice>: 01a88000 set_response_error: handle_get_value GetProhibited
Aug 29 17:39:24 Esters-iPad mobile_installation_proxy[2054] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder LSApplicationProxy: aka-strax
Aug 29 17:39:24 Esters-iPad mobile_installation_proxy[2054] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Not creating progress for LSApplicationProxy: aka-strax since it is not a placeholder.
Aug 29 17:39:24 Esters-iPad installd[1988] <Notice>: 0x2c7000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Åka Strax.app" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
Aug 29 17:39:24 Esters-iPad installd[1988] <Error>: 0x2c7000 init_pack_state: Can't stat /var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/AÃäka Strax.app: No such file or directory
Aug 29 17:39:24 Esters-iPad installd[1988] <Error>: 0x2c7000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Could not initialize package state
Aug 29 17:39:24 Esters-iPad installd[1988] <Error>: 0x2c7000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed
Aug 29 17:39:24 Esters-iPad mobile_installation_proxy[2054] <Error>: 0x305000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
Aug 29 17:39:24 Esters-iPad mobile_installation_proxy[2054] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Aug 29 17:39:24 Esters-iPad mobile_installation_proxy[2054] <Error>: 0x305000 handle_install: Installation failed: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x16d28710 {Error=APIInternalError}
```

This is the OSX system log:

```
2015-08-29 17:39:22,511 Xcode[432]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x127be6000): ENTRY, options: {
    PackageType = Developer;
    ShadowParentKey = "file:///var/folders/vh/z7jrdtc16mv_ml4rdf3c_yf40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.4-6E35b/Xcode/";
}
2015-08-29 17:39:22,522 Xcode[432]: copy_string_value_from_device (thread 0x127be6000): AMDeviceCopyValueWithError: 0xe8000016
2015-08-29 17:39:22,522 Xcode[432]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x127be6000): device os is at least 7.0
2015-08-29 17:39:22,522 Xcode[432]: createShadowPath (thread 0x127be6000): ENTRY bundle: /Users/andreas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Aka_Strax-elchrqyqzidfakebtddarrtffemg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AÃäka Strax.app
2015-08-29 17:39:22,523 Xcode[432]: create_shadow_dir_path (thread 0x127be6000): bundle: /Users/andreas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Aka_Strax-elchrqyqzidfakebtddarrtffemg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AÃäka Strax.app
2015-08-29 17:39:22,523 Xcode[432]: createShadowPath (thread 0x127be6000): returning: /var/folders/vh/z7jrdtc16mv_ml4rdf3c_yf40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.4-6E35b/Xcode/93b97a6a8fc08d7d84994efa7c4f96fb/6f5103ee7f37d220cf45535ea8fb76a2de87a5e4/AÃäka Strax.app
2015-08-29 17:39:22,523 Xcode[432]: createSiblingInPath (thread 0x127be6000): returning: /var/folders/vh/z7jrdtc16mv_ml4rdf3c_yf40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.4-6E35b/Xcode/93b97a6a8fc08d7d84994efa7c4f96fb/6f5103ee7f37d220cf45535ea8fb76a2de87a5e4/ManifestCache.plist
2015-08-29 17:39:22,569 Xcode[432]: _AMDeviceCopyInstalledAppInfo (thread 0x127be6000): no app info
2015-08-29 17:39:22,572 Xcode[432]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x127be6000): unable to get installed app info, falling back to old skool install
2015-08-29 17:39:22,572 Xcode[432]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x127be6000): Blasting the bundle over to the device in an old skool way
2015-08-29 17:39:22,572 Xcode[432]: AMDeviceSecureTransferPath (thread 0x127be6000): disableDelta: TRUE, unzipOnFly: TRUE, StagingPath: PublicStaging
2015-08-29 17:39:22,572 Xcode[432]: AMDeviceSecureTransferPath (thread 0x127be6000): Trying SZConduit for transfer
2015-08-29 17:39:22,613 Xcode[432]: copy_string_value_from_device (thread 0x127be6000): AMDeviceCopyValueWithError: 0xe8000016
2015-08-29 17:39:22,661 Xcode[432]: nuke_path (thread 0x127be6000): AFCRemovePath of 'PublicStaging/AÃäka Strax.app' returned 8
2015-08-29 17:39:22,662 Xcode[432]: AMDeviceSecureTransferPath (thread 0x127be6000): AMDeviceSecureTransferPath:1864 starting delta_transfer_directory, ref_afc: 0x0
2015-08-29 17:39:24,064 Xcode[432]: AMDeviceSecureTransferPath (thread 0x127be6000): AMDeviceSecureTransferPath:1867 finished delta_transfer_directory
2015-08-29 17:39:24,127 Xcode[432]: AMDErrorForMobileInstallationCallbackDict (thread 0x127be6000): GOT AN ERROR 0xe8000067
2015-08-29 17:39:24,127 Xcode[432]: perform_command (thread 0x127be6000): There was an error communicating with the service agent: 0xe8000067
2015-08-29 17:39:24,127 Xcode[432]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication (thread 0x127be6000): Old style install failed for (PublicStaging/Åka Strax.app)
2015-08-29 17:39:24,128 Xcode[432]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication (thread 0x127be6000): Could not install package on device: kAMDAPIInternalError
2015-08-29 17:39:24,128 Xcode[432]: _AMDeviceSecureInstallTheBundleAlready (thread 0x127be6000): AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication failed: 
2015-08-29 17:39:24,132 Xcode[432]: _AMDeviceTransferAndInstall (thread 0x127be6000): _AMDeviceSecureInstallTheBundleAlready failed: 0xe8000067
falling back to file delta
2015-08-29 17:39:24,134 Xcode[432]: writeDictToFile:1239 open failed for /var/folders/vh/z7jrdtc16mv_ml4rdf3c_yf40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.4-6E35b/Xcode/93b97a6a8fc08d7d84994efa7c4f96fb/6f5103ee7f37d220cf45535ea8fb76a2de87a5e4/ManifestCache.plist : No such file or directory
2015-08-29 17:39:24,135 Xcode[432]: MDMCacheDirectoryManifest:1313 writeDictToFile failed to write to /var/folders/vh/z7jrdtc16mv_ml4rdf3c_yf40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.4-6E35b/Xcode/93b97a6a8fc08d7d84994efa7c4f96fb/6f5103ee7f37d220cf45535ea8fb76a2de87a5e4/ManifestCache.plist : No such file or directory
2015-08-29 17:39:24,135 Xcode[432]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x127be6000): returning 0xe8000067
2015-08-29 17:42:46,372 Xcode[432]: <DYMobileDeviceTransport: 0x7fed3febc410>: read io failure: Broken pipe (32)
2015-08-29 17:42:46,373 Xcode[432]: CompanionProxy: _SocketReadCallback:128 (0x0x12786d000): Failed to receive response from AMDevice 0x7fed3feb40e0 {UDID = a84bc06ca4b54d9a575d111abe0a09d7a7b2377a, device ID = 8, FullServiceName = e0:66:78:c2:06:34@fe80::e266:78ff:fec2:634._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local.}: 0xe8000084
2015-08-29 17:42:46,374 Xcode[432]: CompanionProxy: _SocketReadCallback:200 (0x0x12786d000): Stopped listening for paired devices from AMDevice 0x7fed3feb40e0 {UDID = a84bc06ca4b54d9a575d111abe0a09d7a7b2377a, device ID = 8, FullServiceName = e0:66:78:c2:06:34@fe80::e266:78ff:fec2:634._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local.}: 0xe8000084
```

Update:
This is, obviously, an error pertaining to special characters, but the problem from my point of view is:

- Which project properties are used as a base for the filenames? `Product Name` has been suggested -- I don't doubt it -- but is there any documentation on this? I can't find any official description of the purpose of that property. What I *did* find was a description of that property as "user facing", which has to be incorrect. Surely there isn't a user facing property in iOS 7 that only allows ASCII?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem! You need to change your product name under build settings for iOS 7. Special characters are not allowed for iOS 7 devices (**Å**ka Strax)

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. I might try it next time, but the only documentation about Product Name I've come across indicates that it is a user facing property, and my product isn't called anything else. It installs fine from the App Store. Works fine in simulator too.