# IOS: What is the purpose of the project attribute "product name"?

Tags: ios, property-list, xcode-project

I [ran into a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32287926/220820) where the solution seems to be to rename the "product name" property of my project.

I have tried to find an official description of this property, but I failed. What I *did* find was some Apple documentation that described it as "user facing". It's hard to accept that a user facing property doesn't reliably allow for anything but ASCII, so I have to ask: **what is the purpose of "product name"?** (other than an intermediary to derive other properties from)

**Update:** Also, if possible, would be interested in some sort of documentation. I've googled `site:apple.com ios PRODUCT_NAME` without much success.

Comment: You answered your own question at the very end.

Comment: If that's so, that means that the question I linked to should have a different answer. Would you happen to know which property I actually need to change to resolve the file naming error that occurs?

Comment: Why does that change the answer? The "product name" is used to derive the property used for the filename. Since that has a restriction, it means you need to restrict "product name" to the same restriction.

Comment: It changes the answer because my product is not called anything else just because another *separate* property doesn't support the value of `product name`. If there is a property that derives from `product name` then that's the property that should be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [a reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW69) that (kind of) describes the property and what depends on it:

> **PRODUCT_NAME**
>   **Description:**
>   Identifier. Specifies the name of the product the target builds.
>   **Default value:**
>   The name of the target at the time it was created.
>   **Example value:**
>   MyProduct
>   **Affects:**
>   EXECUTABLE_NAME, WRAPPER_NAME.